Why is my Django app running out of memory after switching to Gunicorn?
I got the following error when trying to run a ML/AI app in Django/Docker. The app allows a user to upload audio files which are then transcribed. I started getting the following error after switching to Gunicorn. I understand it is due to memory allocation limitations, but I am not sure how to fix it. The error is inconsistent and only happens with some files and not with others and it is not always the same error. Sometimes I only get a internal server error. The error also happens with longer audio files even if a shorter audio file is larger(so a 10MB, 20 sec audio file may be successful but a 2MB, 3 min file is never successful and always returns a similar error):
 [2024-06-18 08:56:09 -0500] [19] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19)
web-1  | [2024-06-18 13:56:10 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:19) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
web-1  | [2024-06-18 13:56:10 +0000] [34] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 34
web-1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whisper/__init__.py:63: UserWarning: /root/.cache/whisper/tiny.pt exists, but the SHA256 checksum does not match; re-downloading the file
web-1  |   warnings.warn(
 78%|█████████████████████████████        | 56.6M/72.1M [00:24<00:05, 2.74MiB/s][2024-06-18 13:57:18 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:34)
 79%|█████████████████████████████        | 56.7M/72.1M [00:24<00:06, 2.42MiB/s]
web-1  | [2024-06-18 08:57:18 -0500] [34] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 34)
web-1  | [2024-06-18 13:57:19 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:34) exited with code 1
web-1  | [2024-06-18 13:57:19 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:34) exited with code 1.
web-1  | [2024-06-18 13:57:19 +0000] [45] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 45
web-1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whisper/__init__.py:63: UserWarning: /root/.cache/whisper/tiny.pt exists, but the SHA256 checksum does not match; re-downloading the file
web-1  |   warnings.warn(
 72%|██████████████████████████▊          | 52.2M/72.1M [00:24<00:10, 2.03MiB/s][2024-06-18 14:02:49 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:45)
 73%|██████████████████████████▉          | 52.4M/72.1M [00:24<00:09, 2.22MiB/s]
web-1  | [2024-06-18 09:02:49 -0500] [45] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 45)
web-1  | [2024-06-18 14:02:49 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:45) exited with code 1
web-1  | [2024-06-18 14:02:49 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:45) exited with code 1.
web-1  | [2024-06-18 14:02:49 +0000] [56] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 56
web-1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whisper/__init__.py:63: UserWarning: /root/.cache/whisper/tiny.pt exists, but the SHA256 checksum does not match; re-downloading the file
web-1  |   warnings.warn(
100%|█████████████████████████████████████| 72.1M/72.1M [00:22<00:00, 3.39MiB/s]
web-1  | [2024-06-18 14:20:30 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:56)
web-1  | [2024-06-18 09:20:30 -0500] [56] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 56)
web-1  | [2024-06-18 14:20:31 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:56) exited with code 1
web-1  | [2024-06-18 14:20:31 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:56) exited with code 1.
web-1  | [2024-06-18 14:20:31 +0000] [79] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 79

I ran docker stats to analyse memory usage. This is the output:
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   0.06%     571.5MiB / 7.387GiB   7.56%     278MB / 9.01MB    0B / 0B     13
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.00%     19.68MiB / 7.387GiB   0.26%     20.8kB / 18.1kB   0B / 0B     7
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   0.06%     571.5MiB / 7.387GiB   7.56%     278MB / 9.01MB    0B / 0B     13
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.00%     19.68MiB / 7.387GiB   0.26%     20.8kB / 18.1kB   0B / 0B     7
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   0.03%     571.5MiB / 7.387GiB   7.56%     278MB / 9.01MB    0B / 0B     13
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.03%     19.68MiB / 7.387GiB   0.26%     20.8kB / 18.1kB   0B / 0B     7
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   0.03%     571.5MiB / 7.387GiB   7.56%     278MB / 9.01MB    0B / 0B     13
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.03%     19.68MiB / 7.387GiB   0.26%     20.8kB / 18.1kB   0B / 0B     7
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   0.02%     571.5MiB / 7.387GiB   7.56%     278MB / 9.01MB    0B / 0B     13
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.01%     19.68MiB / 7.387GiB   0.26%     20.8kB / 18.1kB   0B / 0B     7
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   0.02%     571.5MiB / 7.387GiB   7.56%     278MB / 9.01MB    0B / 0B     13
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.01%     19.68MiB / 7.387GiB   0.26%     20.8kB / 18.1kB   0B / 0B     7
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   0.93%     571.5MiB / 7.387GiB   7.56%     278MB / 9.01MB    0B / 0B     13
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.72%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.7kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   0.93%     571.5MiB / 7.387GiB   7.56%     278MB / 9.01MB    0B / 0B     13
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.72%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.7kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   3.78%     571.5MiB / 7.387GiB   7.56%     278MB / 9.02MB    0B / 0B     13
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.00%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.8kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   3.78%     571.5MiB / 7.387GiB   7.56%     278MB / 9.02MB    0B / 0B     13
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.00%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.8kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   106.80%   681.8MiB / 7.387GiB   9.01%     279MB / 9.04MB    0B / 0B     14
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.00%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.8kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   106.80%   681.8MiB / 7.387GiB   9.01%     279MB / 9.04MB    0B / 0B     14
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.00%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.8kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   11.82%    692.5MiB / 7.387GiB   9.15%     279MB / 9.05MB    0B / 0B     14
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.01%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.8kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   11.82%    692.5MiB / 7.387GiB   9.15%     279MB / 9.05MB    0B / 0B     14
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.01%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.8kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   9.66%     697.1MiB / 7.387GiB   9.22%     280MB / 9.06MB    0B / 0B     22
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.00%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.8kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   9.66%     697.1MiB / 7.387GiB   9.22%     280MB / 9.06MB    0B / 0B     22
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.00%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.8kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   5.36%     697MiB / 7.387GiB     9.21%     280MB / 9.06MB    0B / 0B     22
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.00%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.8kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   5.36%     697MiB / 7.387GiB     9.21%     280MB / 9.06MB    0B / 0B     22
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.00%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.8kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   5.86%     697MiB / 7.387GiB     9.21%     280MB / 9.07MB    0B / 0B     22
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.00%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.8kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   5.86%     697MiB / 7.387GiB     9.21%     280MB / 9.07MB    0B / 0B     22
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.00%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.8kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   6.62%     697.1MiB / 7.387GiB   9.22%     281MB / 9.08MB    0B / 0B     22
0ac4bc893e43   djangoprojects-db-1    0.00%     21.15MiB / 7.387GiB   0.28%     21.8kB / 19.5kB   0B / 0B     8
CONTAINER ID   NAME                   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O   PIDS
dab126e56daf   djangoprojects-web-1   6.62%     697.1MiB / 7.387GiB   9.22%     281MB / 9.1MB     0B / 0B     13

I can see that in the Net I/O section, memory usage is greater than the limit. However, I'm not sure how to make the necessary changes and I'm not sure if that is even the actual problem. I also read that simply increasing the Gunicorn timeout setting is only a band-aid solution.
Here is my requirement.txt:
aiohttp==3.8.5
aiosignal==1.3.1
asgiref==3.7.2
async-timeout==4.0.3
attrs==23.1.0
certifi==2023.7.22
chardet==5.2.0
charset-normalizer==3.2.0
colorama==0.4.6
Django==4.2.1
django-environ==0.11.2
filelock==3.12.4
fire==0.5.0
fonttools==4.42.1
frozenlist==1.4.0
gunicorn==21.2.0
idna==3.4
Jinja2==3.1.2
llvmlite==0.41.0
lxml==4.9.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
more-itertools==10.1.0
mpmath==1.3.0
multidict==6.0.4
networkx==3.1
numba==0.58.0
numpy==1.25.2
openai==0.27.8
openai-whisper @ git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git@0a60fcaa9b86748389a656aa013c416030287d47
opencv-python==4.9.0.80
packaging==23.2
Pillow==10.0.0
pypdf==3.15.4
PyPDF2==3.0.1
python-dotenv==1.0.0
python-magic==0.4.27
regex==2023.8.8
reportlab==4.0.4
requests==2.31.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
sympy==1.12
termcolor==2.3.0
tiktoken==0.3.3
torch==2.0.1
tqdm==4.66.1
typing_extensions==4.6.2
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==2.0.4
yarl==1.9.2
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
environs[django]==9.5.0
whitenoise==6.1.0
django-storages[s3]==1.14.2

Here is my Dockerfile:
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-bullseye

# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR off
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV COLUMNS 80

#install Debian and other dependencies that are required to run python apps(eg. git, python-magic).
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --force-yes nano python3-pip gettext chrpath libssl-dev libxft-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev ffmpeg git libmagic-dev libpq-dev gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set working directory for Docker image
WORKDIR /code/

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . .

Here is my dockerfile-compose.yml(containing my gunicorn command):
#version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    #command: python /code/manage.py runserver  0.0.0.0:8000
    command: gunicorn mysite.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 # new
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      -  8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      -  "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=secret"
      -  "DJANGO_DEBUG=True"
      -  "DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False"
      -  "DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS=0" 
      -  "DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS=False"
      -  "DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD=False"
      -  "DJANGO_SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False" # new
      -  "ACCESS_KEY_ID=key_id"
      -  "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret_key"
      -  "STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=spaces"
      -  "S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN=domain"
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
volumes:
  postgres_data:

I'm completely stumped. Any help is much appreciated.

NET I/O only means how much data you have downloaded (I) and how much you sent (O) so I don't think it's related. Could you share your gunicorn command? Is your app already deployed somewhere or is it running locally on your machine?

@PTomasz Hi. I added my docker-compose.yml file containing my gunicorn command. I'm doing the tests on my app locally but I have a version running online that produces the same errors. Thanks

Are you sure you have added it? I can't see compose file

@PTomasz Can you see it now? At the bottom of the post

Yes, sadly nothing wrong wit it. Is your system really running out of memory? From what I can see you have 8GB of memory on your machine and django container  is using around 600MB of it. Before killing worker, does your performance manager (top for example) show something unusual?

@PTomasz It really doesn't seem to be running out of memory.  Memory usage doesn't seem to go above 700MB/7.21GB. And CPU usage seems to not go above 100%/800%. So nothing unusual. ChatGPT suggested I use Celery to handle the data processing because it may be taking too long so Gunicorn stops it since if it goes longer than 30 secs without returning Gunicorn thinks it has timed out. It sounds sensible to me. What do you think?

Yeah, worth a try, you can also try to increase worker and threads amount so multiple requests in the same time on your app can be better handled
